# Module directory modules/queues.tf does not exist or cannot be read

Tags: terraform, terraform-module

I am trying to setup terraform with modules and when doing `terraform init` after creating a module I have ran into an issue where I am told it does not exist or can't be read. I've checked many times and tried many paths to it and it does exist where I think it does.

Not sure in that case why it can't be read. I've included my main.tf file as well as the modules/queues.tf file

```
main.tf
  | main.tf
  | modules
     | queues.tf
```

main.tf

```
# This file brings together all of the modules
variable "environments" {
  type = list(string)
}


module "pae_queues" {
    source = "./modules/queues.tf"

    environments = "${var.environments}"
}
```

queues.tf

```
variable "environments" {
  type = "list(string)"
}

resource "aws_sqs_queue" "email_queue_${var.environments[count.index]}" {
  count = length(${var.environments})
  name                      = "email_queue_${var.environments[count.index]}"
  delay_seconds             = 0
  max_message_size          = 2048
  message_retention_seconds = 86400
  receive_wait_time_seconds = 10
  redrive_policy            = "{\"deadLetterTargetArn\":\"${aws_sqs_queue.terraform_queue_deadletter.arn}\",\"maxReceiveCount\":3}"

  tags = {
    Environment = "${var.environments[count.index]}"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Terraform module is represented by a whole directory, not an individual file. If you create a directory `./modules/queues` and move `./modules/queues.tf` to `./modules/queues/queues.tf` then you can call that module like this:

```
module "pae_queues" {
  source = "./modules/queues"

  environments = var.environments
}
```

Comment: I had tried moving it to it's own directory (after posting) but was calling still a specific file in that directory but that failed. So I just have to call the directory not any particular file?

Comment: Yes, a Terraform module is a directory of `.tf` files, not an individual `.tf` file.

Comment: Thanks, i just needed to do source ="./modules" for me!